# opening a socket in mod_fastcgi process in c

Tags: c, linux, apache, sockets, mod-fastcgi

I am using mod_fastcgi with apache webserver, I have made a module in c which cater fastcgi request and also act as TCP Server which communicate with some other module-x acting as client. It works fine when only one such module runs.

But when i configure to run another similar module, Both the process gets same file descriptors when  socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) is called and when new connection is accepted from module-x, which results in unexpected behaviour while sending messages to module-x.

HTTP Configuration

FastCgiServer /scripts/first.fcgi -processes 1 
FastCgiServer /scripts/second.fcgi -processes 1

Any one can help please .......

Thanks,
TC